# Error redirecting to page under Areas section

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net5

I have an *Index.cshtml* Razor Page under my *Areas* section.

[image]

And I'm trying to redirect to that page with the following code.

```
return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = BusinessType.Storage });
```

But this produces an error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index' matches the supplied values.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectToPageResult result)

I don't quite understand this error, or why my redirect isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a break point to check `BusinessType.Storage`, the issue might relate it.

Besides, try to use the following code:

`return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "Storage" });`

Comment: In fact, this was the issue. Although, `BusinessType.Storage.ToString()` equals *Storage*, and I can use `BusinessType.Storage` in tag helpers, it causes a problem here. Adding `ToString()` at the end resolves the issue.